# Do beard growth oils increase beard growth speed?

Tags: hair, medications

There are several topical oils that promise to speed up the growth of beards.

Here's an example of the type of product I'm talking about: [Beard Growther on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00K3VKR6S)

> About the Product
>
> - Grow Your Beard Super Fast
> - All Natural Oils

Its reviews are a ton of 5 stars as well as some middling ones, and then a lot of 1 stars as well. The typical uncommon distribution at the tails of a controversial/polarizing/too good to be true product.

However, it has so many 5 stars that I have trouble believing that they're all due to astroturfing, so I'm curious if it actually does work for some people.

Is there any truth to this?

Here are some related questions, but they are not the same:

- [Does onion juice increase hair growth?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22732/does-onion-juice-increase-hair-growth)
- [Does heavy exercising increase beard growth?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22647/does-heavy-exercising-increase-beard-growth)
- [Does eating brewer’s yeast increase hair growth?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22675/does-eating-brewer-s-yeast-increase-hair-growth?rq=1)
- [Do biotin supplements increase hair growth and strength?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8057/do-biotin-supplements-increase-hair-growth-and-strength) (This one seems like it could be close, but I don't know if there is biotin in the oil.)

Comment: Since "beard growth oils" is a pretty broad term, it might be better to edit the question to ask specifically about the one product you've identified. As far as notability, amazon.com is an unusual source, but given that this product is the "#1 best seller in Beard Conditioners and Oils" on that site, I think it counts.

Comment: I note that the Amazon page points to BeardFarmers.com, which has a [page with references to support their claims](http://beardfarmers.com/growther-beard-enhancing-vitamins/). I suggest that would be a good starting point for an answer.

Comment: I don't know of any studies, but the way it is supposed to work is simple and plausible. The nett rate of beard growth is a balance between growth rate of individual hairs, and rate of loss of hairs. The oils are supposed to reduce the rate of loss by lubricating the hairs, so they don't get caught on things as often.